# Proving the fibonacci sequence satisfies $F_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}C(n-k,k)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

This question before this was:
Strings of the digits $1$ and $2$ are to be constructed having sum $n$. The strings may be of any length, and order is regarded as important.
Let $a_n$ be the total number of strings with sum $n$.
Explain why
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$
with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$.

Hence, prove that
$$F_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}C(n-k,k)$$
where $F_m$ denotes the $m$th Fibonacci number, with $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1$.

At most I can relate the two questions by: $a_n = F_{n+1}$...but not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first relation the explanation is as follows:

Let $b_n$ be the set of all strings of 1 and 2 with sum $n$. We have

$b_1 =\{1\}, b_2=\{11,2\}, b_3=\{111,12,21\}, b_4 = \{1111, 112,121, 211, 22\}, \ldots$

Note that $b_i$ is being obtained from concatenating 1 to members of $b_{i-1}$ and concatenating 2 to members of $b_{i-2}$. This makes perfect sense because for instance $b_{i-2}$ is the set of strings (of 1 and 2) that sum to $i-2$, so if we concatenate 2 to members of this set we get strings that sum to $i$.

For the second relation the explanation is as follows:

$k$ is the number of 2's that appear in the string. Not that for instance if sum of the string is supposed to be 5, then we can have at most $\lfloor 5/2\rfloor$ 2's.

Comment: I think I see it... it involves finding arrangements of $k$ number of $2$'s in a string of sum $n$?

Comment: @Natash1 $a_n$ is the number of strings (of 1 and 2) with sum $n$. To calculate this number we first consider how many 2's we have. For zero 2's the string will be composed of only 1's. For one 2, we have $n-2$ 1's, so $n-1$ numbers in total, and then choose the placement of the 2 in this string ${n-1 \choose 1}$. For two 2's, we have $n-4$ 1's, so $n-2$ numbers in total, and then choose the placement of the two 2's in this string ${n-2 \choose 2}$, etc. So $a_n$ equals the summation on the RHS. Final thing is to note that from the first relation it follows that $a_n=F_{n+1}$.